# how to change style (CSS) of jquery ui datapicker

Tags: javascript

i am new in php and javascript. i am using jquery UI datapicker in my webpage. i used this calendar

```
http://jqueryui.com/download
```

its css code is

```
    <style type="text/css">
        /*demo page css*/
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
        .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
        #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
        #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
        ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
        ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
    </style>
```

and html code  is:

```
 <td>Required Date:</td>
  <td>
   <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
             });
   </script>



<div class="demo">

<p><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->


<div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
--some description
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
</td>
```

now the problem is the body style of this calendar implemented on whole page ,while i have another css file of my page.. and if i remove the body style of this calendar then my calendar appears too large.`. i want the size of my calendar is same as mentioned in body style. what should i do.. please need help`

Answer (score 1):

here -> http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ click on theming, you will find some basic classes and you can customize them. just play with the classes until your datepicker looks the way you need it to. if you've tried this and you can't make it work, report progress and we will see what is wrong.

Comment: i have little knowledge about CSS.. i gave new div to html code and put font size in this new div. but that did not work.

Comment: i have solved my problem by using this `.ui-datepicker{ font-size:9px;}`  thank you Oriesok Vlassky :)